# Unable to send mail if one mail not present with ASP

Tags: asp.net, email, smtpclient, newsletter

I've written code for sending a newsletter, all is working fine, but there is a problem if one of the email addresses in the list, doesn't exit or the domain does not exist.

In this case the script stops immediately and the sending of the mail list is not finished.

Here is the part of the code I want to modify.

```
public static void SendMessage(String sender, String recipient, String message, String object) 
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
        mail.Subject = object;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = message;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "my.smtp.com";
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { throw new Exception("AdminEmail - SendMessage >> recipient: " + recipient + " - generic error: " + e.Message); }
}
```

Hope somone can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, 'stops immediately' as in: the exception is raised? that's probably the case which is fine. Are you referring to another level in your code (the caller for example) since this is a function for sending 1 email and not a mail list....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.
From what I can infer from your description your are not handling the exception that is thrown by SendMessage.

Handle the exception in the caller method. Or do a dirty fix as shown below...

This is not a real fix. But will help you understand the issue...You have to determine in your calling method what to do if SendMessage throws an exception.

```
public static void SendMessage(String sender, String recipient, String message, String object) 
        {

       try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
                mail.Subject = object;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = message;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "my.smtp.com";
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 
                  //Just log error and continue to process

            }   
    }
```